Puzzle test IQ treningmozga with stacks of colored squares

Please solve this puzzle for me.
Source: https://www.treningmozga.com/en/iq/iq-test-46/iq-test.php?qu=8&an=2&ot=85

Welcome to PSE (Puzzling Stack Exchange)!  Could you please tell us where you found this puzzle.  Thanks!

Hint:  Look at the top row of the images (with some orange spots).  Do you see a pattern?  What about the middle row?  And lastly, what about the bottom row?

Check for pattern in the topmost block first, you will notice a pattern. Similarly for the other rows. Hence,
White
Brown
White

Welcome to PSE (Puzzling Stack Exchange)!

See individual blocks as rows along the X axis -
For the top row, the pattern is yellow, blank, yellow blank ...
For the middle row, the patter is brown, blank, blank, brown ...
The last row's pattern is blue, blank, blank, blank, blue
Hence the answer is (from top to bottom) blank, brown, blank
